# argument of $z = \sqrt 5 + 5i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that because both $a$ and $b$ are positive it is in the first quadrant and hence $\arg z$ should just equal to $\arctan(b/a)$, but I've been told that the answer is $\arg z= \arctan \sqrt5 $???

Comment: You are right, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Do you know what "$a$" and "$b$" are?

Comment: can you please explain how that is the right answer?

Comment: Here $a = \sqrt5$ and $b = 5$. What do you get by dividing $b$ by $a$?

Comment: Why did you square the real oart when computing arg?

Comment: $$\frac5{\sqrt5}=\sqrt5\;\ldots$$

Comment: my bad, had 'a' and 'b' mixed up cheers

Answer (score 0):

You just need to realize that $$\frac 5{\sqrt 5} = \sqrt 5$$

Answer (score 0):

$$z = \sqrt 5 + 5i=\left|\sqrt{5}+5i\right|e^{\arg\left(\sqrt{5}+5i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{5}\right)^2+5^2}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt{5}+5i\right)i}=\sqrt{5+25}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt{5}+5i\right)i}$$
$$\sqrt{30}e^{\left(\tan\frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}\right)i}=\sqrt{30}e^{\left(\tan\sqrt{5}\right)i}$$